# Get the unique combinations per variable in SAS

Tags: sas

I am attempting to group by a variable that is not unique with a discrete variable to get the unique combinations per non-unique variable. For example:

```
A B
1 a
1 b
2 a
2 a
3 a
4 b
4 d
5 c 
5 e
```

I want:

```
A Unique_combos
1      a, b
2      a
3      a
4      b, d
5      e
```

My current attempt is something along the lines of:

```
proc sql outobs=50;
    title 'Unique Combinations of b per a';
    select a, b
    from mylib.mydata
    group by distinct a;
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are happy to use a data step instead of `proc sql` you can use the `retain` keyword combined with first/last processing:

**Example data:**

```
data have;
  attrib b length=$1 format=$1. informat=$1.;
  input a
        b $
        ;
  datalines;
1 a
1 b
2 a
2 a
3 a
4 b
4 d
5 c 
5 e
;
run;
```

Eliminate duplicates and make sure the data is sorted for first/last processing:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table tmp as select distinct a,b from have order by a,b;
quit;
```

Iterate over the distinct list and concatenate the values of b together:

```
data want;
  length combinations $200; * ADJUST TO BE BIG ENOUGH TO STORE ALL THE COMBINATIONS;

  set tmp;
  by a;

  retain combinations '';

  if first.a then do;
    combinations = '';
  end;

  combinations = catx(', ',combinations, b);

  if last.a then do;
    output;
  end;

  drop b;
run;
```

**Result:**

```
combinations    a

    a, b        1
    a           2
    a           3
    b, d        4
    c, e        5
```

Comment: You could skip the step that creates tmp and check if the value already exists before concatenating.  Something like `if not index(combinations,B) then call catx(", ",combinations,B);`.  I prefer `call catx` to `catx` in these situations as there's no need to put `combinations =` at the start, but it's a minor point

Comment: Interesting... didn't know `call catx()` had that behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: @longfish I'm assuming the example provided was simplified and if so index could return false matches.

Comment: apologies, I haven't had access to here for a couple of days.  You're right, the `index` function as used here works for the example code, but there could be problems where the text lengths are different for each row.  `indexw` would be a better option

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put a `distinct` keyword in the `select` clause, eg:

```
title 'Unique Combinations of b per a';
proc sql outobs=50;
select distinct a, b
  from mylib.mydata;
```

The `run` statement is unnecessary, the sql procedure is normally ended with a `quit` - although I personally never use it, as the statement will execute upon hitting the semicolon and the procedure quits anyway upon hitting the next step boundary.